# Weekly appointments for a fixed number of weeks with some exceptions

Tags: org-mode

## Level 1

Let's say I have an appointment on Monday each week for the next 3 weeks.
If I include <2024-01-01 Mon +1w> I get an appointment in my agenda that occurs each Monday indefinitely until I manually change it.

I expected that if I write <2024-01-01 Mon +1w>--<2024-02-01 Mon> I will have an appointment that continues each Monday for the next month but instead what happens is I have an appointment *each day* for the next month.

Is there a way to make it so that I the appointments actually stop showing up in the calendar after one month?

## Level 2

The next level of complication for me is that I actually have the appointments on Monday *and* Tuesday, so I am guessing the best way to deal with that is to write two recurring appointments with the same ending date, unless there is a way to specify both Monday and Tuesday in the same appointment block.

## Level 3

Finally, if on the 2nd week there is a holiday so that I can't attend one of the appointments, how can I make it so that the appointment doesn't show up in the agenda on that day?

Comment: See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/how-to-repeat-an-appointment-within-an-interval - people have been asking for a "clever" way to do that for a long time, but AFAIK as I know nobody has come up with a general method, not even for an end date and no exceptions. Using `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` and manually adding however many repetitions you need (and deleting whatever exceptions you want) is, again AFAIK, the best way available.